# JavaScript Calculator alert dont divide by 0

Tags: javascript, calculator

**i have to do alert about dont divide by 0, how do it**

```
<!doctype html> 
<html lang="pl"> 
<head> 
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>ZAD 5 - Kalkulator</title>
<meta name="owner" content="Adam Mika" />
<meta name="description" content="dskjadhjkhgkjdgkjgdkasgds" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="lewa">
MENU:<ul>
<li><a href="zad1.html">Zadanie 1</a></li>
<li><a href="zad2.html">Zadanie 2</a></li>
<li><a href="zad3.html">Zadanie 3</a></li>
<li><a href="zad4.html">Zadanie 4</a></li>
<li><a href="zad5.html">Zadanie 5</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="prawa">
ZADANIE 5 - Kalkulator
<br></br>
        <form name="kalk">
            <table align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td >
                        <input name="txtEkran" type="text" value=0 readonly />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" value=7 onclick="cyfraClick(7)" />
                        <input type="button" value=8 onclick="cyfraClick(8)" />
                        <input type="button" value=9 onclick="cyfraClick(9)" />
                        <input type="button" value="/" onclick="operatClick('/')" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" value=4 onclick="cyfraClick(4)" />
                        <input type="button" value=5 onclick="cyfraClick(5)" />
                        <input type="button" value=6 onclick="cyfraClick(6)" />
                        <input type="button" value="*" onclick="operatClick('*')" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" value=1 onclick="cyfraClick(1)" />
                        <input type="button" value=2 onclick="cyfraClick(2)" />
                        <input type="button" value=3 onclick="cyfraClick(3)" />
                        <input type="button" value="-" onclick="operatClick('-')" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" value=0 onclick="cyfraClick(0)" />
                        <input type="button" value="=" onclick="rownaClick()" />
                        <input type="button" value="+" onclick="operatClick('+')" />
                        <input type="button" value="CE" onclick="kasuj('CE')" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
        </div>

        <script src="zad5.js">
        </script>
      </body>
   </html>
```

JS CODE

```
var formKalk = window.document.kalk;
            var operat;
            var cyfraPierwsza = true;
            var walor1 = 0, walor2 = 0;

            function cyfraClick(cyfra){
                if (cyfraPierwsza || formKalk.txtEkran.value == 0){
                    formKalk.txtEkran.value  = cyfra;
                    cyfraPierwsza = false;
                }else{
                    formKalk.txtEkran.value += cyfra;
                }
            }

            function operatClick(opr){
                var txtEkran = formKalk.txtEkran.value;
                walor1 = parseFloat(txtEkran);
                operat = opr;
                cyfraPierwsza = true;
            }

            function rownaClick(){
                var rezultat;
                var txtEkran = formKalk.txtEkran.value;
                walor2 = parseFloat(txtEkran);
                if(operat == "/") {
                rezultat = walor1 / walor2;
                }else if(operat == "*") {
                    rezultat = walor1 * walor2;
                }else if(operat == "-"){
                    rezultat = walor1 - walor2;
                }
                else {
                    rezultat = walor1 + walor2;
                }

                if(rezultat == Infinity) rezultat = 0;




                formKalk.txtEkran.value = rezultat;
                walor1 = rezultat;
                cyfraPierwsza = true;
            }


            function kasuj(c){
                formKalk.txtEkran.value = 0;
                cyfraPierwsza = true;

                if (c == "C"){
                    walor1 = 0;
                    operat = "";
                }
            }
```

---

What do you think is causing it?

Comment: Causing **what**?

Comment: Please read [ask] then edit question and provide a proper problem statement and explanation of what your code is expected to do

Comment: i have to do alert in JS about dont divide by 0

Comment: in function rownaClick()

Comment: That is not a proper explanation

Comment: You got an error when you posted this question informing you that it can't be all code. You circumvented that with garbage text instead of actually fixing your crappy question. That's quote a rube thing to do... *Asking on Stack Overflow is a privilege, not a right*. Don't abuse that privilege.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a rather simple solution - check to see if `walor1` has the value of zero before dividing. If so, tell the user to not divide by zero, and exit the function. Otherwise, perform the division.

```
if(operat == "/") {
   if (walor2 == 0) {
      alert("Please don't divide by zero.");
      return;
   }
   rezultat = walor1 / walor2;
}
```

Comment: @KamilCzaderna no problem :)